# Error in pages: a cobalt blue error was thrown

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

While editing some standard Wiki pages, I have noticed this ugly pattern. Once in a while randomly but on all people and all browsers simply clicking on a page calls the A blue cobalt error was thrown. If you refresh the error goes away and the page is visible.

I am not sure if the error is related to this other unusual behaviour: at times (again randomly) the modified value and version is not updated, even tho the page is properly saved and checked out, shows the modification, but the modified value still gives you the previous date.

Anybody has a clue? I also have logs of the error but I do not understand exactly where the problem is.  It mentioned something about distributed cache but the service is up and running.

The error appears in pages that have a normal script editor with an iframe google map and another script to remove column heading in lists but I am not sure how this could be related.

Sharepoint on premise 2013